# Web.Config file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Can u tell me exact practical view of configuration section of web config

here is one example

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="Everywhere" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Comment: What do you mean? exact practical view?

Comment: means section name and section group used here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to know what it means?

It is defining custom sections for your web.config. You should see

...
Somewhere bellow in the config file.

They are all from Microsoft the first three being from EnterpriseLibrary.
The rest are used for AJAX support in ASP.NET.

If you're wondering what this means:

```
System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
```

It's a fully qualified type name:

Class name:

```
System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection
```

Assembly name:

```
System.Web.Extensions
```

Assembly version:

```
Version=3.5.0.0
```

Culture of the assembly (language):

```
Culture=neutral
```

And public key token:

```
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35
```

The public key token is part of the public key which uniquely identifies the assembly (dll).

Answer (score 1):

The XML just defines custom config handlers that happen to be created by some MS devs, but could have come from anyone.

This section:

```
<section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Lets a custom config element be used, e.g:

```
<loggingConfiguration somesetting="test" />
```

The type attribute is used by reflection to bind a custom config class to the loggingConfiguration XML element.

From MSDN: [Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)
And here's an excellent blog post on the basics: [The Very Basics of a Custom ConfigurationSection](http://www.csharpconsultant.net/post/2009/01/07/The-Very-Basics-of-a-Custom-ConfigurationSection.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the information,,i know something but i want to know more thats why